# @Resource injection in Servlet stopped working in Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, dependency-injection

I have been running a production web server in Tomcat 7 and then 8.0 for years. Just updated to the current build of Tomcat 9 and all of a sudden my @Resource injections are not working. We use @Resource to obtain javax.mail sessions for sending mail via SMTP. The usage pattern is text-book simple, the servlet is like this:

```
@WebListener
public class EventListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Resource(name = "mail/sesmail") // Injection of mail session by servlet container
  private Session mailSession; 
  ...
  MimeMessage mailItem = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
  mailItem.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddr));
  ...
  Transport.send(mailItem);
```

We had no reference in web.xml for this resource before, but the Tomcat 9.0 docs say you should, so we added this to web.xml (which declares itself a 3.0 servlet):

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>mail/sesmail</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And finally the application context.xml contains the definition of the resource:

```
<Resource name="mail/sesmail" auth="Container"
        type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
        mail.smtp.host="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        mail.smtp.auth="true"
        mail.smtp.port="587"
        mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
        mail.user="xxx"
        mail.password="xxx"
        username="xxx"
        password="xxx"
/>
```

All this works fine in Tomcat 7 and 8, but in Tomcat 9 the mail source does not get configured and goes to the default "localhost:25" which obviously does not work.

Tomcat 9 has been around awhile, cannot believe something as basic as this (and that worked in the prior version) does not work...

Comment: What does *stopped working* mean? what does exactly happen? how do you know it does not work? do you see any logs? want to see/share them?

Comment: PS. We can manually look up the resource and it works correctly:

    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    this.mailSession = (Session) envCtx.lookup("mail/sesmail");

Comment: My question was different. Please read it again.

Comment: "Stopped working" means the configuration of the mail source is not injected, so (as documented in the Tomcat docs) javax.mail uses a default host name "localhost" and port 25. Resulting in this exception: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

Comment: Ok, wait. `com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect* does not necessarily mean that mail source is not injected. Have you tried to debug it? (just print maybe.. whether it gets injected).. because, what if mail server is not accepting a connection? can you connect to it via other interface?

Comment: Look at the host and port number the mail source used "localhost, 25", it is not the configuration specified in the <resource> of the context.xml. It is the default mail configuration used when it does not find any configuration (that behavior is documented here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions). A direct lookup works correctly, so the @Resource injection did not work - it did not provide the proper JNDI resource (which DOES exist, proven by the fact that I can do a manual lookup and find it).